# What does actually reasonable mean when we say "reasonable model of computation"?

Tags: turing-machines

I have seen in many text when the author says "reasonable model of computation". What does it really mean?

Comment: it would be helpful to cite a few contexts. basically its likely referring to computation models with physical implementations/ limitations. there are some abstract models that do not fit that.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have a precise meaning. What an author considers "reasonable" largely depends on the context. It is usually meant to exclude certain pathological cases.

Comment: cases ... like?

Comment: ... like esentially all of [hypercomputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation).

Answer (score 3):

In computational complexity theory, Peter van Emde Boas formulated the *Invariance Thesis* saying that:

> 'Reasonable’ models of computation can simulate each other within a polynomially bounded overhead in time and a constant-factor overhead in space.

See eg [Cambridge Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computational-complexity/).

Reading this thesis as a definition, one can call a *reasonable model of computation* a model of computation that is equipped with a time complexity measure which is polynomially equivalent to counting steps on a Turing machine (ignoring space complexity for the moment).

I have used the term in this sense in my own work [here](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/DICE2016/Abstracts/paper_6.pdf).